# Регулярка которая проверяет промежуток в скобках

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

написать регулярку которая проверить есть ли в строке "{a,b}"  вот такая констукция и если есть проверит что a не меньше 1 а b не больше 3 к пример, вместо 1 и 3 могут быть любые числа

Comment: а причем здесь `React`?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let test = `
  x {0,3}
  √ {1,3}
  x {1,4}
  √ {11,3}
  √ {111,-5}
`;

console.log( test.match( /\{(\d\d+|[1-9]),(-\d+|[0123])\}/g ) );
```

**a >= 1**: `(\d\d+|[1-9])`

            `\d` от слова digit - цифра. `+` "один или больше совпадений"

            `\d\d+` - двузначное число, или больше.

            `|` или числа от 1 до 9.

**b <= 3**: `(-\d+|[0123])\}`

            `-\d+` любое отрицательное (целое) число

            или числа 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а что делать если ты не знаешь какие a и b придут а они к примеру приходят динамически каждый раз разные

Comment: @AleksandrMatyka выражение и рассчитано на любые a / b в указанном диапазоне...

Answer (score 0):

1. Регулярными выражениями нельзя сравнить числа. Регулярные выражения служат для поиска заданного шаблона в тексте. Обработку чисел необходимо производить программно.
2. Ниже приведен пример обработки чисел программно. В консоль выводятся найденные числа и результат сравнения первого со вторым.

```js
let text = `
 {0,3}
 {1,3}
 {1,4}
 {11,3}
 {111,-5}
`;
let regex = /\{(-?\d+),(-?\d+)\}/g;
let process = ( groups ) => {
    let g1 = parseInt( groups[1] );
    let g2 = parseInt( groups[2] );
    console.log( g1, g2, g1 > g2 );
};

for ( let oneMatch of text.matchAll( regex ) ) process( oneMatch );
```